# Import from cl-user package

Tags: lisp, package, common-lisp, conventions

Is it good idea to import something from `cl-user` package? As far as I know, contents of this package are not specified by the standard, so does import of functions from `cl-user` package break compatibility of a program? For example I use GNU CLISP and I want to use `xor` and `!` functions in my program, I've imported them from `cl-user` package, but how do I know that other implementations include these functions as well? Is there any conventions or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CLISP, both `xor` and `!` are externals of the `EXT` package, not `CL-USER`. They are not standard functions, so you cannot rely on their existence when writing portable code.

You could write something along these lines to use the built-in functions on CLISP and homebrewn ones on other LISPs:

```
(in-package :my-package)

#+CLISP
(import 'ext:xor)
#-CLISP
(defun xor (&rest what)
  ;; your own xor implementation
  ...)

#+CLISP
(import 'ext:!)
#-CLISP
(defun ! (&rest what)
  ;; your own ! implementation
  ...)
```

Comment: Hm.. it seems like I might always use only my own implementations of these functions writing even less code.

Answer (score 3):

`Xor` is also in [alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/), but with a bit different semantics.

It is a good idea to use wrapper libraries that encapsulate implementation-specific behaviour under a portable interface.  This makes your code more portable, or at least facilitates making it more portable.